# Deleted OAUTH client for production flutter app

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-play, google-oauth, android-app-signing

I am using flutter for developing an application with [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) package. We had some unnecesary clients in our google cloud console. I accidentaly deleted the one used for the production app. I created a new one with the same SHA-1 fingerprint as the old one, but the oauth client gives the following error.

```
PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
```

If I generate a new keystore file and add it to the cloud console, the login works. But I can't upload the application to the play store because the keystore file has changed.

We should roll out an update in the next few days, what are my options?